# Connection between "Cauchy" delta function and "Fourier" delta function?

Tags: fourier-transform, dirac-delta, cauchy-integral-formula

A delta function has the sampling property, it picks out the value of a function $f(x)$ at a point $a$
$$
f(a) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \delta(x - a) f(x) dx
$$
The Fourier integral theorem says
$$
f(a)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ipa}\left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{ipx }f(x)\,d x \right) \,dp 
=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty \left(\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ip(x-a)} \,dp \right)f(x)\,d x 
$$
so the "Fourier" delta function can be defined as $\delta(x-a)=\frac{1}{2\pi} \int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-ip(x-a)} $.

However the sampling property is also true for Cauchy's integral formula
$$
f(a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \oint_{\partial D} \frac{f(z)\,dz}{z-a}
$$
So the "Cauchy" delta function is $\delta(z-a) = \frac{1}{2\pi i} \frac{1}{z-a}$.

So this looks different. However is it really different? It is often possible to use contour integration and Cauchy's integral formula to compute Fourier integrals . So I was wondering: is there a direct connection between both representations of the delta function, if one chooses an appropriate contour to compute the contour in Cauchy's integral formula so that basically Cauchy's integral formula becomes equal to the Fourier integral theorem?

Comment: The Cauchy formula is rigorous as an integral; the $\delta$ integral is not, as it does not converge. You need distribution theory to really make sense of the Dirac delta

Comment: The situation is very different. Cauchy's integral holds only for holomorphic function on some open set containing the closed disk, whereas « delta » integral is valid for all continuous functions.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan - not all continuous functions. For the Fourier integral, $f$ has to vanish at $\pm\infty$ fast enough for the integral to converge.

Comment: @Paul Sinclair I was talking about the « integral » $\int \delta(x-a) f(x) dx$.

Comment: @ChristopheLeuridan - but since that one is strictly a pretense (as is the right hand form of the Fourier integral, but the LH is well-defined), there is no need to restrict it even to continuous functions.

Comment: This is the way the Dirac delta is defined in the context of Hyperfunctions https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hyperfunction, an extension of the theory of distributions.